# C++/CLI: is it possible to target the .NET 3.5 Client Profile using Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, c++-cli, .net-client-profile

I have a C++/CLI library that I'd like to target the .NET 3.5 SP1 Client Profile, but the client profile does not appear in the list of available frameworks. Is it possible to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible – if not through the UI, then at least by manually editing your `App.config` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" sku="Client" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Edit your `App.config` file so that its `supportedRuntime` element matches the above.

Comment: He's already using that runtime version, VS2008 only targets CLR v2.  This is a build question.

Comment: @nobugz : Enforcement of client runtime is performed by the CLR at execution time; the `sku` attribute is the key change that must be made.

Comment: @Adam, please use my SO user name, that way your comments show up in my inbox.

Comment: @Hans Passant : Fair enough. A question, though, that I couldn't find an answer to with a skim of the FAQ: When using '@' to respond to people with a space in their name, is it necessary to use the full name or only the first name in order to have the message appear in their inbox?

Comment: I just use the first 3 letters, getting the space included.  Can't say if that's guaranteed to work but nobody ever said it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-intro-client-profile.aspx) tries to explain that you need to get the SP1 for VS 2008 in order to access that target (but it's not completely clear that that's exactly what they are saying).