# How to target the .NET 4 Client Profile for C++/CLI under Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601605/c-cli-is-it-possible-to-target-the-net-3-5-client-profile-using-visual-studi) describes selecting it for .NET 3.5 under VS2008.
How does one select the .NET 4.0 Client profile for C++/CLI under VS2010?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After experimenting with a C# project, I found that manually adding a TargetFrameworkProfile node to the vcxproj file seems to do the trick.

Procedure:
1) Using a plaintext editor, open the vcxproj
2) Find the PropertyGroup node 
3) Find the TargetFrameworkVersion node under PropertyGroup
4) Add a TargetFrameworkProfile node as shown in this snippet:

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
   ...
   <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>   
   <TargetFrameworkProfile>Client</TargetFrameworkProfile>
   ...
```

After saving the vcxproj file and reloading the project inside Visual Studio, open the project's Properties and select **Common Properties**. The **Targeted framwework** will now display "Profile=Client"
[image: Screenshot showing Client Profile]

Comment: You deserve a nice answer badge +1!